# What is the best way to filter collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, collections, laravel

I am thinking a best solution at the same time a lazy solution to filter collection in eloquent result in Laravel. I want to filter all my $videos collection in all my controllers. Is that possible to do without rewriting the controllers and instead put it in the model?

Here is my filter code:

```
$videos = $videos->filter(function( $video ){
        return $video->isPublished();
    });
```

Comment: I think my best card is to add a scope in all of the queries.

Comment: What does `isPublished()` do? A simple boolean column in the database or something more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use query scopes. You can learn from [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes). And in your case, it would be something like this:

```
class Video extends Eloquent {
    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('published', '1');
    }
}

class VideosController extends BaseController {
    public function showPublishedVideos()
    {
        return View::make('published_videos')
                   ->with('videos', Video::published()->take(10)->get());
    }
}
```